# Create Folder from new Google sheet Row

Tags: google-apps-script

Hope that somebody can help me. I create a Google script for New Folder include Hyperlink. (very new in Script)

For some reason it gives no Errors but it also creates No Folders..
The Hyperlink must be in Column R and the Name of the Folder is from the last row Column a,b together.

(is there also a possibility to Copy a existing Template Folder to a New Folder)

```
function createAndHyperlink() {
    var ss, sh, parent, parent2, r, v, thisCell, folder
    ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    sh = ss.getSheetByName('MOC Permanent')
    parent = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents().next();
    parent2 = DriveApp.getFolderById("1vxS3FebsDLqrGGQc9kG7cE3tO9zN8Qre")
   r = sh.getLastRow()
   v = sh.getMaxColumns()
      for (var i = 0, l = v.length; i < l; i++) {
        thisCell = sh.getRange(i + 3, 2)
        if (v[i][0] && !thisCell.getFormula()) {
            folder = parent2.createFolder(v[i][0]);
            thisCell.setFormula('=HYPERLINK("' + folder.getUrl() + '"; "' + v[i][0] + '")');
        }
    }
}
```

Google Sheet :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12n2Cmu6OqZskD_j7YhVrU14qaQPPGnQyIoSEIw8stqE/edit?usp=sharing

Hope somebody can help me

Comment: I need to see and image of your spreadsheet.  Note: I will not follow offsite links.

Comment: This code `if (v[i][0] && !thisCell.getFormula())` makes absolutely no sense.  v is not even declared as an array.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your post correctly, you want to create Sub folders named after every row data on column `A` + Column `B` inside of your Parent Folder. Then, get each link of the Sub Folders and add each of these links on Column R as `HYPERLINKS`.

**RECOMMENDATION**

I have tweaked your current script and you may use this sample script below as reference:

***UPDATED***

```
//MAIN SCRIPT TO RUN
function createAndHyperlink() {
    var ss, sh, lastRow, name;
    ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    sh = ss.getSheetByName('MOC Permanent');
    lastRow = sh.getDataRange().getLastRow();

    for(var row=2; row<=lastRow; row++){
      name = sh.getRange(row,1).getValue()+sh.getRange(row,2).getValue();
      if(sh.getRange(row,18).getValue().toString()==""){
        sh.getRange(row,18).setFormula('=HYPERLINK('+"\""+createFolder(name).getUrl()+"\",\""+name+"\")");
        Logger.log("Created a folder for "+"Name:\n"+name);
      }else{
        Logger.log("R"+row+" contains a hyperlink already!");
      }
    }

    //THIS CODE BELOW ENSURES THE LAST ROW OF COLUMN R WAS ADDED WITH HYPERLINK BEFORE COPYING FUNCTION BEGINS
    if(sh.getRange(lastRow,18).getValue().toString()!=""){
      addTempFileCopy();
    }
}

//FUNCTION TO CREATE SUB FOLDERS INSIDE THE PARENT FOLDER
function createFolder(folderName){
    var parent, folders, firstLevelFolder, newfolder;

    parent = DriveApp.getFolderById("PARENT_FOLDER_ID").getName();
    folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(parent);
    firstLevelFolder = (folders.hasNext()) ? folders.next() : DriveApp.createFolder(parent);

    //CREATE UNIQUE SUBFOLDERS INSIDE OF THE PARENT FOLDER
    newfolder = firstLevelFolder.createFolder(folderName);
    return newfolder; //RETURNS THE LINK OF THE CREATED SUBFOLDER
}

//FUNCTION TO ADD THE TEMPLATE FILE INTO EACH CREATED SUB FOLDERS
function addTempFileCopy(){
    var parent, subFolder, ss;

    ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    parent = DriveApp.getFolderById("PARENT_FOLDER_ID").getFolders();

    while(parent.hasNext()) {
      subFolder = parent.next();
      var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(subFolder.getId()); 
      DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).makeCopy(subFolder.getName()+" - Template file copy", destFolder);
      Logger.log("Template file name: "+ss.getName()+"\nAdded to folder: "+subFolder.getName());
    }

}
```

**SAMPLE SHEET**

[image]

**RESULT**

*After running the script, `HYPERLINKS` were added on the on `COLUMN R`:*

[image]

*Here are the created Sub folders on Google Drive inside of the Parent folder:*

[image]

*Execution log result:*

[image]

Comment: Yes this works Create. Is it then also possible to start this when a New Row is added and that it creates A copy of a subfolder of a Template Subfolder (with extra subfolders and template Files?)

Comment: Sorry - People now make a Copy of the Template (sub)Folder with related File Templates in this SubFolder. So they always have the correct files to fill in. So When it is creating the "new folder" can we include direct the File templates

Comment: I have updated the script on my answer. I've added a function (addTempFileCopy()) that makes a copy of the template spreadsheet file on each newly created sub folders.

Comment: No the active spreadsheetsheet is copied into the new folder. But I need to have a Copy from an TemplateFolder which is on an other Drive with Template Files into the "new Created" Folder. The Active Spreadsheet is only an Overview sheet

Comment: Apologies, I'm unable to fully undertand/visualize the "need to have a Copy from an Template Folder which is on an other Drive with Template Files into the "new Created" Folder". Isn't the Spreadsheet file that contains "'MOC Permanent'" sheet the template file? Can you please re-edit your original post above and add a step-by-step process of the specific goal you want to achieve?

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding. First step - New Row in the "MOC" sheet which create the NEW FOLDER. Only the NEW Folder is a COPY of Folder with Template Files in it.  (link to Folder https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1PDtK47YcCfFQtFjYRoLk54Brug3JbohF?usp=sharing)

Comment: You can put the main function into an onEdit() trigger (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#getting_started) where once you add/edit a new row o your sheet, the script will auto run and create a new folder for the new row. As for creating a new folder that contains a copy of the template folder w/ template files in it, unfortunately, there's no simple way of implementing it, according to an answer at https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/40214. However, you can refer to an advanced implementation from https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/60321.

Comment: Also, please NOTE that one Stakoverflow post should only focus to one specific problem/question, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Thus, I have corrected/tweaked your code which wasn't working properly on creating folders then setting up the HYPERLINKs. Since the other question is specific to copying a Google Drive folder w/ files into a newly created folder, it would be better if you can post a new question specific for this process Or you can, again, refer to the implementation recommended from webapps.stackexchange.com/a/60321 (GDrive Copy Folder).

Comment: It works only not the the CopyFile is done everytime the Script runs instead of once by create New folder